# nc not waiting for server disconnect on OS X

Tags: osx, socket, netcat

How to make `nc` client on OS X Mavericks keep socket open and read data until server disconnects the socket?

I want to send data to a server through `nc` and then use the response. Problem is that `nc` disconnects the socket after the data has been sent, without waiting for the server's response.

This will just write the data then exit:

```
$ echo "my instruction here" | nc 127.0.0.1 $MY_PORT
```

This will write the data and then not exit even though the server has disconnected:

```
$ cat <(echo "my instruction here") - | nc 127.0.0.1 $MY_PORT
```

The `nc` man page on OS X Mavericks have the following example for sending a `HTTP GET` request and printing the response, but it's not working. It just sends the request then exits without waiting for the server's response. Seems like the man page's information is incorrect?

```
$ echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc host.example.com 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to keep writing something to the socket - once data can't be written `nc` will exit.

`(echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; (while true; do echo -e "\n"; sleep 1; done)) | nc example.com 80`

This will send empty line to `nc` once every second until `nc` can't write to socket and `nc` will exit.

Thanks to Steffen Ullrich for his answer and comments that guided me to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of nc is to close the connection if stdin is closed. To change you can use the -q option (like `-q -1`) on Linux, it might be the same on OS X. See the man page for details.

Edit: looks like OS X nc does not support -q switch or anything similar. In this case you need to make sure that stdin gets not closed by doing somehing like this:

( echo "foo"; sleep 100000 ) | nc ...

Comment: There is no -q option for the nc included with OS X

Comment: see edited response for a workaround

Comment: Thanks, but still not getting any response. Tried modifying the nc man page example: `(echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; sleep 1000) | nc example.com 80`

Comment: The example is wrong. To make echo interpret `\r\n` as CR LF you have to use the `-e` option for echo, i.e. `echo -ne "foo\r\n"`

Comment: Cool. With -e it's working. However I need nc to exit when the server disconnects the socket.

Comment: OS X bundles an old nc version it seems. I'd really like to use that default one if possible. If not possible I'll have to resort to installing a newer one.

Comment: There is no "server closed connection". There is only "server will not send more data, but might still receive more". And you only know if you try to send more data if they server accepts them.  That's how TCP works. And it looks like nc will not exit as long as it can send all data from stdin and stdin is not closed.

Comment: True. A way to make nc exit when the socket is closed is to keep sending data for example empty lines. It'll exit when it can't be sent. Know of a way this can be achieved with a while loop?

Comment: Got it. `(echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"; (while true; do echo -e "\n"; sleep 1; done)) | nc example.com 80`

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the listening `nc` (server) gets closed, the client `nc` quits as well.

On Mac OS X you can `open -a 'Activity Monitor'` to verify that.

The reason why the `nc & cat` example hangs is not `nc` but `cat` that continues to keep its stdin and stdout open for reading and writing.

However, when `cat` tries to write to the pipe after the listening `nc` has been closed, `SIGPIPE` is raised and `cat` terminates.

```
# cat & SIGPIPE test
(sleep 1; echo hi) | 
   (trap 'echo "received signal $(($? - 128))" 1>&2' EXIT; cat) | :

kill -l 13
man bash | less -p 'EXIT STATUS'
man bash | less -Ip '128\+n'
```

As an alternative to the workaround by Niklas Berglund it is possible to trap the exit of the client `nc` to kill the whole process group including the hanging `cat` command.

```
# console 1
# ctrl-c will "kill 0" entire process group sh -c '...'
nc -l 8080  

# console 2
# script command (FreeBSD version) will implicitly run: man 2 setsid
# kill 0 will therefore only kill the entire process group sh -c '...' 
# run in a script kill 0 would otherwise kill the entire script
# cf. also https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid 
script -q /dev/null sh -c '
(echo "my instruction here"; cat) | (trap "kill 0" EXIT; nc 127.0.0.1 8080)
'
```